# Eloquent Query with Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question about how to generate a query with eloquent and I would appreciate any help from you.

I have 4 tables in my database:
1. modules
2. roles
3. module_rol (pivot table)
4. regions

Structure of the tables:

1. modules:
   id int
   name string
   region int
   active bool
2. roles
   id int
   name string
3. module_rol
   rol_id int
   module_id int
4. regions
   id int
   name string

I need to get all the values ​​from the modules table with some conditions for example ..

```
public function getUserModules($rol, $region)
{
 // Return all modules to which that role is allowed to access and have that region defined
}
```

While waiting for some help, thank you very much in advance

**EDIT 1:**

```
Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('region')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('region')
                ->references('id')->on('regions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });



Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



Schema::create('module_rol', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('rol_id');
            $table->integer('module_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('rol_id')
                ->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('module_id')
                ->references('id')->on('modules')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: can you post the relationships with the models?

Comment: Thanks!..See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define ManyToMany relationship between Module and Role using pivot table

> Module Model

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'module_rol');
}

public function region(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Region::class, 'region');
}
```

> Role Model

```
public function modules(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class, 'module_rol');
}
```

> Fetch Data

```
public function getUserModules($role, $region)
{
 // Return all modules to which that role is allowed to access and have that region defined
    $modules = Module::where('region', $region->id)
                     ->whereHas(['roles' => function($query) use ($role) {
                        return $query->where('role_id', $role->id)
                     }])->get();
    return $modules;
}
```

Details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many